# sum values based on match criteria to another table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to sum prices in one table based on a match criteria from another table
example table 1

```
Grocery Items            Price
Apples                    $2
Oranges                   $3
Bread                     $4
Milk                      $5
```

but lets say i want to sum based on a table 2:

```
Milk
Apples
Oranges
```

But tomorrow I want to change table 2 such that:

```
Milk 
Bread
```

How would I sum the prices of the items in the table 1 based on what is in table 2?

Comment: Your question isn't clear now, please clarify it? What is the source data? What needs to be calculated?

Comment: Always quantity one?  Have you looked at looking up each table 2 item in table 1 and adding its price to table 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`VLookUp`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to get the price for the list in table 2, and then sum it:

[image: VLookUp in Table2]

Note that you can have Table 2 in another sheet.